# Powershell - Speeding up writing to files

Tags: performance, powershell, replace, find

I wrote this script to find all of the folders in a directory and for each folder, check inside a common file if some strings exist and if not add them. I needed to insert strings in particular places. Not really knowing how to do this, I opted for simpler find and replace where the strings needed to be inserted. Anyway this script takes almost an hour to work through 800 files. I'm hoping some experienced members can point out ways to make my task quicker as I have only been working with Powershell for two days. Many Thanks!!!

```
# First find and replace items. 
$FindOne = 
$ReplaceOneA = 
$ReplaceOneB = 
$ReplaceOneC = 

# Second find and replace items. 
$FindTwo =
$ReplaceTwo =

# Strings to test if exist.
# To avoid duplicate entries.
$PatternOne = 
$PatternTwo = 
$PatternThree = 
$PatternFour = 

# Gets window folder names.
$FilePath = "$ProjectPath\$Station\WINDOW"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem $FilePath | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"}

# Adds folder names to an array.
$FolderName = @()
$Folders | ForEach-Object { $FolderName += $_.name }

# Adds code to each builder file.
ForEach ($Name in $FolderName) {

$File = "$FilePath\$Name\main.xaml"
$Test = Test-Path $File

# First tests if file exists. If not, no action.
If ($Test -eq $True) {

$StringOne = Select-String  -pattern $PatternOne -path $File 
$StringTwo = Select-String  -pattern $PatternTwo -path $File 
$StringThree = Select-String  -pattern $PatternThree -path $File 
$StringFour = Select-String  -pattern $PatternFour -path $File

$Content = Get-Content $File

# If namespaces or object don't exist, add them.
If ($StringOne -eq $null) {

$Content = $Content -Replace $FindOne, $ReplaceOneA
}

If ($StringTwo -eq $null) {

$Content = $Content -Replace $FindOne, $ReplaceOneB
}

If ($StringThree -eq $null) {

$Content = $Content -Replace $FindOne, $ReplaceOneC
}

If ($StringFour -eq $null) {

$Content = $Content -Replace $FindTwo, $ReplaceTwo
}

$Content | Set-Content $File

}

}

# End of program.
```

Comment: given 800 files, you're actually doing up to 3200 find/replace runs, since you're processing each file **FOUR** times in your loop...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any ideas on making it simpler but achieving the same outcome?

Comment: load the file once, then do your foreach/set-content runs? never really used powershell, though, so no idea whether you have to get-contents each time to load the freshly modified versions.

Comment: You're right. No need to get-content multiple times. I will see how much that speeds it up. If other members see further improvements in best practice, please chime in... Thanks Marc!

Comment: @MarcB has the right approach. Just make sure you set the content of `$content` each time you do a replace i.e. `$content = $content -replace $FindOne, $ReplaceOne`. Once you've done each you can do `$content | Set-Content $File`

Comment: @arco444 thanks for the response. I've not been able to test yet, but I've edited. Is this what you're thinking? I've removed the for-each object as it was wholly unnecessary for my purpose. But I only started learning the past couple of days, so it was just some code that I managed to find that worked - but wasn't that well-suited ha!

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing to the file with a stream, like this

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $File
$stream.WriteLine($content)
$stream.close()
```

Comment: Hi, I've not come across this approach. I wrote as you wrote it, but it filled every file with the string and nothing else "System.Object[]"?

Comment: Hi, I used "$Content" and it outputted just fine. However, its important to keep the text formatting. I take it this is not possible with streamwriter and I guess even the point of it, in that you don't care? Cheers!

Comment: You can still write it out line by line if you need to, my example was just a simple one to illustrate the idea.

Comment: can you point me in the right direction. Would I need to create an array containing each line of my content to then write out? Thanks again!